# Export FireBug Data

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I know there are [plugins to export FireBug data](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/exporting-http-tracing-data-from-firebug/), but adding new plugins to our environment is difficult.  Is FireBug raw data available in JavaScript or HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NetExport](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/netexport/)